# Sql query about joining 2 select

Tags: sql, select

I would like to know how can i join 2 select statements that are like this:

```
Select Team.name from Team join Match on Team.id == Match.teamHomeid
Select Team.name from Team join Match on Team.id == Match.teamAwayid
```

The error i get is cause i dont have separate IDs for Home and Away teams

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Do one SELECT only. Let Match join team twice, one time for home and one time for away. Use table aliases.

Comment: This is the data (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hugomathien/soccer) _soccer_ and from this i want to get the output of home and away teams for a specific match

Comment: A link to where you get the data is not what @Sergey meant as sample data. Anyway check the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same table multiple times. ie:

```
Select t1.Name as HomeTeam, t2.Name as AwayTeam 
from Match m
inner join Team t1 on t1.Id = m.teamHomeId
inner join Team t2 on t2.Id = m.teamAwayId
```

Comment: The t1 and t2 are needed to be Team cause the table that contains the name of the teams are not on Match table. The common thing is that in match you have the home and away team ids. So the problem is that i cant use the Team.name twice to get the away team name too

Comment: Sorry m8 i checked yours pretty fast and i didnt get to i understand it. The problem I had is that I didnt know that you can name the same table like that twice! And without that i got ambiguous name error. Although now that i checked it again, you are right this is also a solution! Thank you and sorry for confusing you!